# How do I generate a new SOAP webservice from Maven?

Tags: maven, web-services, soap, glassfish, payara

I have to produce a documentation for my team. This documentation should show how to generate a webservice project from scratch, compile it and deploy it into a payara (glassfish) server

To realize this project, I wrote a simple project whose main files are :

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.inrae.sicpa</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyServiceWS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MyServiceWS</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>MyServiceWS</finalName>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
    <!-- main -->
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <!-- test -->
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.properties</include>
          <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            <warSourceExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</warSourceExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyServiceWS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/payara-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE payara-web-app PUBLIC 
          "-//Payara.fish//DTD Payara Server 4 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/payara/Payara-Server-Documentation/master/schemas/payara-web-app_4.dtd">
<payara-web-app>
    <context-root>/MyServiceWS</context-root>
</payara-web-app>
```

**/src/main/java/fr/inrae/sicpa/services/IMyService.java**

```
package fr.inrae.sicpa.services;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(name="IMyService", targetNamespace="http://services.sicpa.inra.fr")
public interface IMyService 
{
    public double getPrixTTC( double ht );
    public double getPrixHT( double ttc );
    public double getTVA( double prix, boolean isTTC );
}
```

**/src/main/java/fr/inrae/sicpa/services/MyServiceImpl.java**

```
package fr.inrae.sicpa.services;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService(serviceName="MyServiceWS", portName="MyServicePort", endpointInterface="fr.inrae.sicpa.MyServiceWS")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)
public class MyServiceImpl implements IMyService
{
    private final static double TAUX = 0.196;
    
    @WebMethod(operationName="getPrixTTC")
    @WebResult(name = "ttc")
    @Override
    public double getPrixTTC(double ht) 
    {
        return ht * (1 + TAUX);
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName="getPrixHT")
    @WebResult(name = "ht")
    @Override
    public double getPrixHT(double ttc) 
    {
        return ttc / (1 + TAUX);
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName="getTVA")
    @WebResult(name = "tva")
    @Override
    public double getTVA(double prix, boolean isTTC) 
    {
        if(isTTC)
            return prix - (prix/(1 + TAUX));
        else
            return prix * TAUX;
    }
}
```

At this stage, I manage to generate my project structure, compile the project and deploy it on my payara server (5.192). But what I don't understand is that neither the wsdl file nor the endpoint are created at deployment time.

I've been struggling with this since the end of December. Where do you think my error lies?

Thank you very much for your help

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to RagnarosLightLord on Discord :

> Hi
> There is an apache plugin named cxf-java2ws-plugin to pregenerate
> your wsdl file when compiling maven.
> Look on this side, it will help you
> Good luck
> RagnarosLightLord

Here is how to modify the pom.xml to be able to generate the wsdl file when compiling maven :

```
  <build>
    ...
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-wsdl</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
              <attachWsdl>true</attachWsdl>
              <className>fr.inrae.sicpa.services.MyServiceImpl</className>
              <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}.wsdl</outputFile>
              <!-- See here for options http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html -->
              <databinding>jaxb</databinding>
              <frontend>jaxws</frontend>
              <genClient>false</genClient>
              <genServer>false</genServer>
              <genWrapperbean>false</genWrapperbean>
              <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
              <quiet>false</quiet>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>java2ws</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
    ...
  </build>
```